# Scala-pass value to the function as parameter

Tags: scala

I am beginner in scala,i have created two functions.I need to pass output of **time** function to the input to **delayed** function.I need to pass b value 5 to delayed function as parameter.

```
object Demo {

   def main(args: Array[String]) {

        delayed(time());


   }

   def time() = {

      println("Getting time in nano seconds")

      val b=5

      return b

   }

   def delayed( b: => Long ) = {

      println("In delayed method")

      val a=b+10000

      println("Param: " + a)

   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this what you are going for:

```
object Demo {

   def main(args: Array[String]) {
        delayed(time());
   }

   def time(): Long = {
      println("Getting time in nano seconds")
      5L
   }

   def delayed(b: Long): Unit = {
      println("In delayed method")
      val a = b + 10000
      println(s"Param: $a")
   }
}
```

Note how types are declared with a colon(`:`), the use of string interpolation (`s""`) and how there is no need for a return statement (the last line executed in the block is returned).